# What are conditional features in C standard?

Tags: c

> This third edition cancels and replaces the second edition, ISO/IEC
> 9899:1999, as corrected by ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor 1:2001, ISO/IEC
> 9899:1999/Cor 2:2004, and ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor 3:2007. Major changes
> from the previous edition include:
>
> — conditional (optional) features (including some that were previously
> mandatory)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)#Optional_features .

Comment: In C11 see footnote **3)** in section **§4** page **8**: *A strictly conforming program can use conditional features (see 6.10.8.3) provided the use is guarded by an appropriate conditional inclusion preprocessing directive using the related macro. For example: `#ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__`  `fesetround(FE_UPWARD);` `#endif`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.8.3 1 lists the conditional feature macros, which reveal the conditional features:

> `__STDC_ANALYZABLE__` The integer constant `1`, intended to indicate conformance to the specifications in Annex L (Analyzability).
>
> `__STDC_IEC_559__` The integer constant `1`, intended to indicate conformance to the specifications in Annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic).
>
> `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` The integer constant `1`, intended to indicate adherence to the specifications in Annex G (IEC 60559 compatible complex arithmetic).
>
> `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` The integer constant `201710L`, intended to indicate support for the extensions defined in Annex K (Bounds-checking interfaces).
>
> `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__` The integer constant `1`, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support atomic types (including the `_Atomic` type qualifier) and the `<stdatomic.h>` header.
>
> `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` The integer constant `1`, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support complex types or the `<complex.h>` header.
>
> `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` The integer constant `1`, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support the `<threads.h>` header.
>
> `__STDC_NO_VLA__` The integer constant `1`, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support variable length arrays or variably modified types.

Comment: implementation of those part of the standard is not mandatory for a compiler builders? and/or rather implementing certain libraries among this list is not mandatory?

Comment: @NusratNuriyev: The C standard does not distinguish the compiler and the library; everything that contributes to translating and executing a C program is the C implementation. Yes, C implementations that do not implement these conditional features may be conforming to the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional (optional) features are features that are not necessary supported by C compiler implementations as for example variable length arrays or complex types.